# How not to have a cut matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

**General Issue:** My visualisation is cut on the edges and I found a way to correct it manually. *But is there a command that could do it itself ?*

I'm using Pyzo to code Python (`Python 3.9.5`) with `Matplotlib.pyplot` (version 3.4.2)

- When I want to see a graph that I plotted (with `plot.show()`) command I get the plot in a separate window but it appeared cut (especially the edges : titles) as shown in the image below :
  [image: Cut plot]
- Then, I tried to put it in full-window. It is slightly better but still cut (especially the top) :
  [image: Still cut]

So I started looking into the parameters which were accessible in the `Subplot Configuration Tool`, and by changing the `top`value, I was able to make my plot completely viewable:

- `Subplot Configuration Tool`:[image: Subplot Configuration Tool]
- After modification of `top` value to `0.95`:[image: Good visualisation]

**Thus**, I was wondering if there was a way to change the value directly in the code instead of having to deal with it manually each time.

***Note :*** In the past, I had to use `figsize=(x_width,y_width)` as a parameter in `plt.subplots()` but it doesn't change anything here (at most, I can have the first picture above)

**Recap :**

- Is there a way to make sure, nothing will be cut in the visualisation of the plot (Title of the plot + Titles of the axis) with a command ?

Comment: you got some hints here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Comment: Recommend https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can do this manually with `plt.subplots_adjust()` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html)
2. you can do this automatically with `plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html)
3. you can do this automatically with `plt.tight_layout()` instead of using constrained_layout.  However, in general constrained layout is more flexible.   https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html